# How can I call the constructor of the derived class when using CRTP?

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

I have the following setup:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct feline {
  void roar() noexcept {
      static_cast<T*>(this)->do_roar();
  }
      feline() noexcept {
      std::cerr << "Feline ctor" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct lion : public feline<lion> {
  lion() noexcept : feline() {
    std::cerr << "Lion ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  void do_roar() noexcept {
      std::cerr << "Lion roar" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct tiger : public feline<tiger> {
  tiger() noexcept : feline() {
    std::cerr << "Tiger ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  void do_roar() noexcept {
      std::cerr << "Tiger roar" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    feline<lion> lion;
    lion.roar();
    feline<tiger> tiger;
    tiger.roar();
}
```

and when I execute it I get the following result:

```
Feline ctor
Lion roar
Feline ctor
Tiger roar
```

Which means the constructors for Lion and Tiger are never called. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Don't you want to instantiate `lion` and `tiger` instead of `feline<lion>` and `feline<tiger>`?

Comment: if you want to create a lion you should write `lion lionx;`

Comment: btw using same names for variables and types is rather confusing

Comment: You call the constructor for both `lion` and `feline<lion>` by constructing an instance of `lion`. I feel like this might be an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @tobi303 I think `lion lion_o` may be more fitting in this case.

Comment: @user4581301 why? because `_o` stands for "object"? If thats your reasoning then I strongly disagree. Naming an object "object" is completely pointless.

Comment: @user4581301 I get it :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you never create an actual lion.

CRTP requires an object of the actual class in order to work properly.

Remember that the base class will never instantiate the child class directly because its all about forcing the class to support some functions and not classical inheritance.

Your code could crash but it doesn't, and that's because the function `do_roar` does not access any private variables. Try adding some members to `lion` and using them in `do_roar`, you'll see...

If you want a lion use the `lion` class, `feline<lion>` is just an instantiation of `feline<T>` where `T = lion`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using CRTP slightly wrong. For a moment forget about the fact that the base class is parametrized on the inheriting class, then what you do is something like:

```
struct feline { };
struct lion : feline {};

feline roary;        // in your actual code this is parametrized with lion
                     // but still it is no lion !
```

when you actually wanted to create a lion:

```
lion roary;          // this is a lion !
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared new classes but did not use them.

Below is a revised `main()` that uses your new classes:

```
int main()
{
    lion l;
    l.roar();
    tiger t;
    t.roar();
}
```

which outputs:

```
Feline ctor
Lion ctor
Lion roar
Feline ctor
Tiger ctor
Tiger roar
```